# Using Delegates with PageViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, protocols, uipageviewcontroller

I have a PageViewController that has 3 child views contained within. I would like to see a simple Objective-C example using protocols/delegates for how I can trigger a method of the PageViewController when a user clicks a button in the child view controllers?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a simple delegation. You can create a page based project which will generate the code for you. After that create the protocol you want with its methods and add a delegate property to the Page child view controller. The only change you need to make is inside the `pageViewController:viewControllerBeforeViewController` and `pageViewController:viewControllerAfterViewController` methods. Before you return the page child controller there set also the delegate and implement the methods from the protocol.

Comment: Im a newb, could you should me an example of how to create this. Lets say I have a TableViewController and PageViewController, what would I need to put in the .h and .m files for each?

Comment: If you are new to this i recommed you to learn this pattern and after you understand how it works you can try to implement the PageViewController. http://cognitivedesign.com/papers/understanding-delegation-in-ios.html